# Yii2 GridView get current page

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a Gridview and want, that only the very first row has another behavior than the others.

```
    [
        'label' => 'col1',
         'value' => function($model, $key, $index) {
            if ($index == 0) {
                //BEHAVIOR 1
                return 1;
            } else {
                //BEHAVIOR 2
                return 2;
            }
        }
    ],
```

My problem is now, that it does behavior 1 on every page at the very first row (apparently only at the first page).

Is it possible to get the current page like getting the row-index with the `$index` variable in my code or is there another way to solve this in a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[
    'label' => 'col1',
     'value' => function($model, $key, $index) use ($dataProvider) {
        if ($index == 0 && $dataProvider->pagination->page == 0) {
            //BEHAVIOR 1
            return 1;
        } else {
            //BEHAVIOR 2
            return 2;
        }
    }
],
```